# Need help with finding the electronic schematics

Tags: datasheet, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to find what kind of circuitry(circuit components or schematics) is used in this anemometer: http://www.nrgsystems.com/sitecore/content/Products/5966.aspx 
There are a lot of details about mechanical parts but not the electronics in their website. It just says it is generating ac sine waves that's all. I want to know whats in the anemometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the "Specifications" tab on [that anemometer page](http://www.renewablenrgsystems.com//Products/5966.aspx),
it specifically says

> Signal type:   low level AC sine wave, frequency linearly proportional to wind speed
>
> ... (more details about the output signal omitted) ...
>
> Magnet:    Indox 1, 25 mm (1 inch) diameter, 13 mm (0.5 inch) long, 4 poles
>
> Coil:  single coil, bobbin wound, 4100 turns of #40 wire, shielded for ESD protection

From those specs, it is almost certainly a fixed-coil, moving-magnet [magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/magneto_%28generator%29) -- a kind of [alternator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/alternator) -- with the wires from the coil coming directly out.
It apparently doesn't have any other "electronics" or "circuits".

It has a coil of wire, and it has a magnet spinning in the center of that coil.
That's it.

They gave you details about each and every electronic part of the device -- both the coil, and the magnet.
I'm a little puzzled -- Why would anyone think "they give no info about it" when their website already lists almost everything there is to know about it?

Could you give a link to a web page about something you've designed, that shows the amount of detail you think is appropriate?

[image]

(Image from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Alternator_1.svg ).

Comment: so does that mean they manufacture also the alternator themselves? I thought they would buy parts and montage them to make up the anemometer.

Answer (score 0):

> Signal type    low level AC sine wave, frequency linearly proportional to wind speed

presumably, a small generator

[image]

Comment: might be. but why do u think they give no info about it? i searched couldn't find a single info.

Comment: @user16307: We can only speculate. For the same reason KFC don't publish their secret recipe? Perhaps they see no commercial benefit to their shareholders in giving you free help to build a competing product?

Comment: sometimes manufacturers show all details in their electronics design even-though they have complicated circuits. this is not a rocket science thing but hey hided it just like coca cola formula.

Comment: @user16307 It's their intellectual property, so it's their choice, isn't it?

Comment: yep i understand but they gave a lot of info about the mechanical part which is the real crucial part for an anemometer. a bit strange.